# Export a large raster to a comma or tab delimited text file in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, point

I have a large raster with multiple attributes in 200-meter cells, and I would like to export this to a tab or comma delimited file which contains the X,Y coordinates and all of the attributes.  If it's possible I'd also like to have the file arranged so it goes East to West across the whole raster like a typewriter.

I'm currently in the process of trying raster to point,  assigning X,Y, to the points and exporting the table.

Answer (score 3):

Export the [raster to ASCII](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000005000000) and then remove the header row and then find & replace space with comma with [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), regular text editors would die on a large file.

If you want XYZ format then use [GDAL_Translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with -of XYZ for [gridded XYZ](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html) format.

Here is a simple python script:

```
import sys, os, arcpy

InImage = sys.argv[1]
OutCSV  = sys.argv[2]

Temp = os.environ.get("Temp")

arcpy.AddMessage("Converting raster to ASCII")
arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion(InImage,Temp + "\\Temp.asc")

arcpy.AddMessage("Writing ASCII as CSV")
with open(Temp + "\\Temp.asc",'r') as ASCfile:
    with open(OutCSV,'w') as CSVfile:
        for ReadLine in ASCfile:
            # skip the header lines by length
            if len(ReadLine) > 50:
                WriteLine = ReadLine.replace(" ",",") 
                CSVfile.write(WriteLine)
            else:
                arcpy.AddMessage("Skipping header line " + ReadLine)

arcpy.AddMessage("Cleaning up")
os.remove(Temp + "\\Temp.asc")
```

Copy the text into a text file and [add it as a script tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Adding_a_script_tool/00150000001r000000/) like this:[image]

Comment: This ASCII output is too large for notepad++,  thanks for the suggestion.   I've never used GDAL,  any tips for getting started with that?  Using with python?  Thanks again

Comment: If you're happy with a python I'll write you something to do just that, it's around a dozen lines. If you want to start with GDAL then install QGIS... easiest way. GDAL_Translate is in the \bin\ folder of the QGIS install or can be accessed by the GUI.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was a great response.   I'll definitely use this in the future.  For now I was able to 'add XY' to a  'raster to point' operation within ArcGIS desktop.  I exported the resulting table to a text file, imported to Access and used a query to join to the original raster attributes (I also rounded some of the coordinates which had 1E-6 variations from integer values).   Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It sounds like you have answered your own Question as a Comment.  Would you be able to write it up as an Answer instead, please?  That way you will be able to Accept it (or the Answer given by @MichaelMiles-Stimson) and close it off.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelMiles-Stimson for saving me a lot of time with this!